# Getting error while installing conda-accelerate

Tags: anaconda, package, installation, gpu, conda

I have been trying to install conda-accelerate to use my GPU's for machine learning algorithm however I am getting following error while installing from anaconda prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\Ege>conda install accelerate
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - accelerate

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Seems like accelerate does not exist anymore: https://docs.anaconda.com/accelerate/

Answer (score 2):

`conda install accelerate` doesn't work, not sure why web is littered with this command when it doesn't work?

The correct way to install is following command, it worked for me on ubuntu.

```
$ conda install -c fastai accelerate
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/ray/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - accelerate


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    accelerate-0.5.1           |             py_0          42 KB  fastai
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:          42 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  accelerate         fastai/noarch::accelerate-0.5.1-py_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
accelerate-0.5.1     | 42 KB     | ############################################################################################################################ | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score -1):

See [PyOpenGL-accelerate](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL-accelerate/) maybe help you.